# admissible ideal of affine rank 3 acyclic quiver $\tilde{A}_{12}$

Tags: representation-theory, quiver

> > Does  affine rank 3 acyclic quiver $\tilde{A}_{12}$ with arrows $2 \to 1$, $3\to 2$ and $3 \to 1$ has admissible ideal?

For any finite quiver $Q$, a two-sided ideal $I$ of $KQ$ is said to be admissible
if there exists $m \geq2$ such that $R^m_Q\subseteq I\subseteq R^2_Q$.

So $\langle 3\xrightarrow[]{\beta}2 \xrightarrow[]{\alpha}1 - 3\xrightarrow[]{\gamma} 1\rangle$ cannot be an admissible ideal. Am I right?

Can $\langle 3\xrightarrow[]{\beta}2 \xrightarrow[]{\alpha}1$ be an  admissible ideal?

If not? So how can we find its indecomposable projective and injective modules?

I appretiate if someone gives me some ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: The condition that an ideal $I$ is admissible if $R^m_Q\subseteq I\subseteq R^2_Q$ really just says that the paths that generate your ideal have to have length at least two, and the paths in your ideal must have bounded length, which since your quiver is finite and acyclic we don't have to worry about. So your first ideal $\langle 3\xrightarrow[]{}2 \xrightarrow[]{}1 - 3\xrightarrow[]{} 1\rangle$ is *not* admissible because of that length-one path $3 \to 1$. The ideal $\langle 3\xrightarrow[]{}2 \xrightarrow[]{}1 \rangle$ is admissible.

Comment: Also, I assume that $R_Q$ is $KQ$, right?

Comment: Many thank for your comment! $R_Q$ is the ideal generated by the arrows in $Q_1$.

Comment: A couple of points.  First, in Mike Pierce's first comment, he says that the paths in the ideal should have bounded length but what he means is that the paths in the quotient should have bounded length.  Second, if you have an ideal that is not contained in $R^2_Q$, you can use elements not in $R^2_Q$ to remove some superfluous arrows.  The quotient by your first ideal is isomorphic to the original quiver with the arrow $\gamma$ removed.